# Change dimension order of numpy shape for image data

Tags: python, numpy, shapes, nifti, memmap

I am using numpy and nibabel lib to load data from nii file.
This is my code to load the image data

```
import os, glob
import nibabel as nib 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

DataInputPath = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Data/Volumes/Img' 
ImgPath = os.path.join(DataInputPath, 'Patient1.nii')
Img = nib.load(ImgPath).get_fdata() 
np.min(Img), np.max(Img), Img.shape, type(Img)
```

And the output (image properties) are as shown below:

"(-1000.0, 2976.0, (512, 512, 193), numpy.memmap)"

When I want to plot the image using matplotlib using the code below, the output images seems like cropped as it using the image shape as above 512x512x193. How do I change the dimension when I want to plot the slice from x and y, so that the image won't be cropped? Plotting the slice z seems okay.

Ex1: Plotting X slice and the image is cropped

```
ImgSlice = Img[100,:,:] 
plt.imshow(ImgSlice, cmap='gray')
plt.imshow
plt.show()
```

[image]

Ex2: Plotting Z where the image is okay

```
ImgSlice = Img[:,:,100] 
plt.imshow(ImgSlice, cmap='gray')
plt.imshow
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: In the first example, `ImgSlice = Img[100,:,:] ` which means the shape of the slice image is [1,512,193] which means only 1 y-axis pixel, you should glob a group of pixels, for example `ImgSlice = Img[:100,:,:]` or `ImgSlice = Img[100:200,:,:]`

Comment: Hi @Toby thanks for you reply. The array is in 3d-dimensional, but there are 4 indexes from your example.

Comment: No, it's 3D, `Img[:100,:,:]` means you take the first 100 elements from the first axis and all elements in others dimension.